# Prevent Vim from concealing characters

Tags: vim

When editing markdown files in vim, '*' and '_' are concealed unless the cursor is on the line.

How can I prevent Vim from concealing characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of fooling around, this seems to be working:

```
:set conceallevel=0
```

Comment: great, you answered your own question is 39 seconds

Comment: @Begueradj I had just figured it out and wanted to document the solution. I think there was a meta article saying it was alright to do that...